# What is SPINX and why is it being used in this ASP.NET Framework 4.5 web site project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have inherited a codebase and one of the stumps is that I do not know what is SPINX. Or BasePAL. This is the code:

`using System;
namespace SPINX.Entity
{
public class ProductCatMappingPAL: BasePAL

}`

Questions:

1. What is SPINX?
2. What is the importance of SPINX in this ASP.NET Framework project?
3. What is the meaning of PAL/BasePAL in the context of this ASP.NET Framework v4.5 web site project?

The PAL definition I've found is "Programmable Logic Array". Seems like it's a fancy word to say "relation type" or "connection"

The things I found on Spinx is two sites: sphinx-doc.org and sphinxsearch.com
Sphinx search seems to focus on python but I'm looking for something C# based

Comment: To me it seems quite clear that this has nothing to do with [tag:sphinx] or [tag:python-sphinx].

Comment: took that tag off. thx

Comment: SPINX looks like the namespace that this codebase itself is using based on `namespace SPINX.Entity`.  BasePAL is most likely a class you would find within the project serving as a baseclass for whatever they consider these PAL entities to be, whether used for some entities or all entities. Often I'll see entities defined with a base class to hold common fields applicable to all entities or a subset of relatable entities. EF also supports inheritance across or within a table as well, though "Base" usually implies a more commonly used base class. Seems you'll have a bit of reading to do.

Comment: Yep. First time working with ASP.NET and C#. However, I asked this question since I couldn't find SPINX online and I thought it might have been a deprecated package. I then found out that it was a custom built class for our codebase and that's why the net didn't have any documentation. @StevePy